# Can I use a different db as a Wolkenkit read model?

Tags: domain-driven-design, graphql, cqrs, event-sourcing, wolkenkit

I like MongoDB ok, but I was thinking about just using postgres as the read model and querying from it with graphQL. Do I have to write an adapter to do that? If so, where should I look to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, it depends

Short answer: No, you can't.

Long answer: Yes, theoretically changing the read model database is possible, as [wolkenkit](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit) uses an adapter-based approach. Right now MongoDB is the only implemented one, but it would be possible to write one, for whatever datastore you want to use.

Basically, the place to start is the [wolkenkit-broker](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit-broker), which is the public API server for wolkenkit, and which also handles reading models. At the center of this there is the so-called [modelStore](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit-broker/tree/cc9015a8cbd8e0fe450dceed365d784767fca9d5/modelStore), which acts as an abstraction layer over the specific implementation, such as the [modelStoreMongoDb](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit-broker/tree/cc9015a8cbd8e0fe450dceed365d784767fca9d5/modelStoreMongoDb) adapter.

GraphQL again is currently not supported out of the box. We use our own approach, implemented in the [tailwind](https://github.com/thenativeweb/tailwind) module. The place to start here is the [HTTP server](https://github.com/thenativeweb/tailwind/tree/74c6cc4fd0892df50871e4817f9c93503cdbb548/lib/wires/api/http/v1) API.

*Please note that I am one of the developers of wolkenkit, so please take my answer with a grain of salt.*

Comment: I don't think the adapter approach would work for a relational database because of needing an ORM. It might be a common scenario for people to want to model outside of wolkenkit and have only projection functionality exposed. Could we offer a folder structure `server/projections` instead of `server/readModel` if people want to go that route?

Comment: This should be possible by using (stateless) flows, as read models are basically nothing but stateless flows with built-in persistence. Am I missing something here?